# Azure Iot Hub C Client Upload to Blob Fails with X.509 Authentication

Tags: c, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using the Azure Iot Hub C SDK with the TI SimpleLink module to connect to an Azure IoT Hub using X.509 authentication. The authentication works for messaging and device twins but fails when I attempt an upload a file to blob storage. If I use symmetric key authentication, the file upload works as expected.

Is file upload with X.509 authentication a supported feature of the Azure IoT SDK for C and the TI SimpleLink implementation?

I know that the C# SDK does not have this problem but there could be differences in an implementation on a PC vs an implementation on a microcontroller. I also saw that there is not support for the Java SDK.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/issues/371

Answer (score -2):

I have had the exact same problem. I can do everything, but not upload a file when using x509.

However, If I create a device using sas token and connect using `IoTHubClient_LL_CreateFromConnectionString` instead of `IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_CreateFromDeviceAuth`, it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)